# Условия проверки длины слова. Классы Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

Стоит задача в написании программы которая будет отбирать самые короткие и самые длинные слова в предложении.
Я начал делать задачу и с гордостью запуская программу понял, что она куда-то теряет первое слово. У меня не получается придумать то, как можно изменить условие чтобы это самое первое слово куда-то распределялось. Я понял что условия составлены неверно, но как их изменить не догадываюсь, прошу помощь Community SO.

```
    class MinMaxWordFinder:
       def __init__(self):
          self.list_longest_words = []
          self.list_shortest_words = []

       def add_sentence(self, sentence):
          sentence = sentence.split()
          shortest_word = "adcdefsfdsdadaadadaa"
          longest_word = "a"
          for word in sentence:
            if len(word) < len(shortest_word):
                shortest_word = word
            if len(word) >= len(longest_word):
                longest_word = word
            self.list_shortest_words.append(shortest_word)
            self.list_longest_words.append(longest_word)
        print("Longest: ", self.list_longest_words)
        print("Shortest: ", self.list_shortest_words)

    finder = MinMaxWordFinder()
    finder.add_sentence("world abc hello")
    finder.add_sentence("def asdf qwert")
```

Вывод следующий:

```
Longest:  ['hello', 'qwert']
Shortest:  ['abc', 'def']
```

А должен быть такой:

```
Longest:  ["world", 'hello', 'qwert']
Shortest:  ['abc', 'def']
```

Comment: Вы или хитро напутали с отступами, или это не тот код, который вы запускаете. Этот код дает совсем другой результат.

Comment: @Эникейщик, да скорее всего я накосячил с отступами, потому что при копировании сюда кода отступы теряются и мог неверно их расставить

Answer (score 1):

Дело не в том, что первое слово теряется. Просто у вас же за каждый прогон `add_sentence` в каждый список добавляется только по одному слову. То есть вообще ни при каком раскладе за два прогона не может в списке оказаться больше двух слов. Даже если в предложении все слова будут одинаковой длины, то из одного предложения только одно слово попадает в списки.

Нужно как-то так:

```
class MinMaxWordFinder:

    def __init__(self):
        self.list_longest_words = []
        self.list_shortest_words = []

    def add_sentence(self, sentence):
        sentence = sentence.split()
        shortest_words = []
        shortest_length = float('Inf')
        longest_words = []
        longest_length = 0
        for word in sentence:
            if len(word) == shortest_length:
                shortest_words.append(word)
            if len(word) < shortest_length:
                shortest_length = len(word)
                shortest_words = [word]
            if len(word) == longest_length:
                longest_words.append(word)
            if len(word) > longest_length:
                longest_length = len(word)
                longest_words = [word]
        self.list_shortest_words.extend(shortest_words)
        self.list_longest_words.extend(longest_words)

        print("Longest: ", self.list_longest_words)
        print("Shortest: ", self.list_shortest_words)


finder = MinMaxWordFinder()
finder.add_sentence("world abc hello")
finder.add_sentence("def asdf qwert")
```

Comment: О каких двух проходах речь? В каждом add_sentence столько проходов, сколько слов предложении.

Comment: @Эникейщик, автор вопроса накосячил с отступами, поэтому не сразу становится понятно. Но если принять во внимание тот вывод программы, который написан в вопросе, то становится очевидно, что append у него выполняется уже за пределами for - только один раз на  каждый вызов add_sentence.

Comment: Понятно, тогда да.

Comment: @Александр , а что означает строка shortest_length = float("Inf") ?

Comment: Это псевдочисловое значение, которое гарантированно больше любого числового значения. Его удобно брать в качестве стартового минимального значения - это гарантия того, что первый же элемент, который мы сравним с этим значением, сам станет новым минимальным значением.